# What was the first commercial scheduled flight to Australia from another continent (except Asia)?

Tags: commercial-aviation, aviation-history

Australia has been a very isolated country, ships being the only possibility to get there from another continent if someone was not too much in a hurry. Aviation did add a new and radically different possibility.

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://ehssjadej.edublogs.org/2015/07/21/asia-australia/)</sup>

When and how did occur the first commercial scheduled non-stop flight to mainland Australia (country) from mainland Americas, Europe, Africa or Antarctica? I'm excluding overseas islands and Asia which are easier challenges.

Comment: @foot, non-stop flights. The idea is also to exclude small overseas islands that may belong to other countries, a 4,000 km flight doesn't qualify :-)

Comment: I hear that a lot, that Australia is far away. But it is right outside my door!

Answer (score 3):

**Background**

Jumping to Asia then Europe is known as the [Kangaroo Route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo_Route). Excluding that, that leaves us with flights directly to/from the Americas and Africa.

Nonstop to London is still unrealized from Sydney. Although Qantas flew London to Sydney nonstop in 1989, but that was a delivery flight. Flying Perth-London nonstop [will begin in 2018](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2016/dec/11/qantas-confirms-non-stop-perth-to-london-flights-from-march-2018) using the Boeing 787. And with the upcoming 777X and A350-900ULR, Sydney-London [should be possible](http://www.smh.com.au/business/aviation/airbus-boeing-close-in-on-qantas-long-haul-dream-the-kangaroo-route-nonstop-20170405-gveotc.html). What that media calls a "Kangaroo Route nonstop dream."

[image]
(gcmap.com - A330-300 typical range) Range map shows how far Australia is, for context.

Circa [August 1957](https://www.flightglobal.com/FlightPDFArchive/1957/1957%20-%201193.PDF) is when Australia signed an Air Service Agreement with the US to operate across the USA and onto Europe. Thus securing an alternative to the Kangaroo Route. [At the time](https://www.flightglobal.com/FlightPDFArchive/1950/1950%20-%200770.PDF) planes were able to reach the West Coast of the US (with many stops) in sea planes such as the Short Solent. Even with the [advent of the jet age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Qantas), the 707 had to make stops in Nadi and Hawaii.

#### The candidates for the first *scheduled* non-stops are:

**Africa:**

> On 6 **January 1977,** the Boeing 747SP made its first scheduled flight between Johannesburg and Sydney. The flight offered in-flight audio entertainment and movies ([flysaa.com](https://www.flysaa.com/about-us/leading-carrier/about-saa/brief-history)).

**Contiguous US:**

[Pan Am](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_in_aviation#November):

> November 4, **1982** – Pan American World Airways inaugurates service from Los Angeles, California, to Sydney, Australia; at 7,487 miles (11,979 km), it is the longest non-stop flight in the world.

[Qantas](https://www.qantasnewsroom.com.au/media-releases/qantas-celebrates-60-years-of-flying-to-the-usa/):

> [2014] marks thirty years since Qantas began non-stop flights between Sydney, Melbourne and Los Angeles beginning in **April 1984.** These services were operated by the long-range Boeing 747SP with a flying time of around 16 hours. Today, the flying time is around 13 hours.